# manifest file not containing an attribute

Tags: java

Thanks for your answers. I'm still having a fault saying manifest file does not contain a file/object attribute, after I had created my jar file for my application. I'm doubting maybe I didn't know what exactly the main-class represent in a manifest file while writing the code. please illustrate taking an example from the HelloWorld .

Thanks

Comment: You could at least accept an answer for your other question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

EDIT:

**Test.java**

```
package pk;

public class Test{
   public static void main(String []args) {
       System.out.println("Hello World");
   }
}
```

**mf** manifest file entry

```
Main-Class: pk.Test
```

**Compilation**

```
>javac Test.java -d .
```

**Create a Jar**

```
>jar -cvfm my.jar mf pk
```

**Test the jar**

```
>java -jar my.jar
```